# what is the role of information matrix in Likelihood estimation?

Tags: econometrics

I couldn't grasp what it refers to exactly so I would like to understand how we use it:

from MLE, Score Vector is:

$$
S(\theta;y) = \frac{\partial l(\theta;y) }{\partial \theta} 
$$
$l$ comes from the **log** version of the likelihood function and this score vector has an asymptotic distribution with Information Matrix which is:

$$
I(\theta) = -E(\frac{\partial l(\theta;y) }{\partial \theta \partial \theta ^T } )
$$

I appreciate it if you can explain how to use it and which sources I can use.

Comment: hi: you'd have to read a fairly advanced book on statistical inference. one recommendation is this one at the link below. there are probably other good ones that I am not aware of so hopefully other recommendations will follow from others. https://www.amazon.com/s?k=jogesh+babu&crid=79Y6OHDJDOEA&sprefix=jogesh+babu%2Caps%2C76&ref=nb_sb_noss

Comment: You may try asking questions like this on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions) instead. You will find a larger pool of experts there.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4037394/covariance-matrix-inverse-and-second-order-derivatives-of-log-likelihood/4037862#4037862 Hope this helps.